# Error: test_project/views/index.hbs: Missing helper: "ifCond"

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am trying to create a custom block helper ***ifCond*** using the registerHelper() method, but it's throwing an error as **Missing helper: "ifCond"**.

Below is given the code-

*test_project/app.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')

todolist = [
    {
        task: 'Task 1',
        status: 'Todo'
    },
    {
        task: 'Task 2',
        status: 'In Progress'
    }
]

Handlebars.registerHelper("ifCond", function(key, value, options) {
    return (key==value) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this)
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Todolist',
        todolist
    })
})

app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    todolist.push({
        task: req.body.task,
        status:req.body.status
    })
    res.redirect('/')
})


app.listen(1111, ()=>{
    console.log('server started at http://localhost:1111')
})
```

*test_project/views/index.hbs*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todolist SSR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="task" id="task" placeholder="Enter the task">
        <select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="Todo">Todo</option>
            <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
            <option value="In Review">In Review</option>
            <option value="Done">Done</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Todo</th>
                <th>In Progress</th>
                <th>In Review</th>
                <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each todolist as |todo|}}
                {{#ifCond todo.status "Todo"}}
                    <tr><td>{{ todo.task }}</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                {{else}}
                    {{#ifCond todo.status "In Progress"}}
                        <tr><td></td><td>{{ todo.task }}</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                    {{else}}
                        {{#ifCond todo.status "In Review"}}
                            <tr><td></td><td></td><td>{{ todo.task }}</td><td></td></tr>
                        {{else}}
                            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>{{ todo.task }}</td></tr>
                        {{/ifCond}}
                    {{/ifCond}}
                {{/ifCond}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

> ***Error: test_project/views/index.hbs: Missing helper: "ifCond"***

Kindly let me know where am I making mistake. I would really appreciate help of any sort.

Comment: You are calling `Handlebars.registerHelper` as you would do in an environment with a global `Handlebars` reference - on which you would call `compile` as well - for example, in a front-end application. As you are using Handlebars on the server and using it is as the view engine for express, this way of registering helpers will not work. You will need to look into using something like [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) and follow its docs on how to register helpers.

Comment: Got it, the documentation in the provided link was very helpful. Thanks!